# wait for useEffect to update state in order to pass down props?

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent component that is fetching data from an api, I would like to fetch it once on render and set it to state and pass it down as props to a child component that will then map over this state. How can I wait for 'bids' to have items before the child component renders? I thought by passing setBids it would wait until bids is set, but instead im getting an empty array to map over

```
function Parent () {

const [bids, setBids] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBids = async () => {
      const result = await api.GetBids();
      setBids(result.body);
    
    };

    fetchBids();
}, [ setBids ]);

return ( <Child bids={bids}/>)

}

export default Parent;
```

```
function Child(props) {

  const { bids, id } = props;
 
  return (
    <Fragment>
      
      {bids.map((responseBidId) => {
          if (responseBidId === id) {
          return (
            <button onClick={handleView}>view</button>
          );
        } else {
          return (
            <Button
              onClick={handleUpload}
            >
              Upload
            </Button>
          );
        }
      })}
    </Fragment>
  );
}

export default Child;
```

Comment: Try async-await in this case

Answer (score 0):

You could wait for `bids` to be populated before rendering the child:

```
const [bids, setBids] = useState();
```

```
return bids ? <Child bids={bids}/> : null;
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 35 seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't "wait", not really. If you think about it more in terms of "when" should I render the child it might help though.

```
function Parent () {

  const [bids, setBids] = useState(null); // <-- change to null to indicate unset

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBids = async () => {
      const result = await api.GetBids();
      setBids(result.body);   
    };

    fetchBids();
  }, [ setBids ]);

  return bids ? <Child bids={bids}/> : null;

}

export default Parent;
```